# How to find and remove optgroup and option in select?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've this select structure:

```
<select id="select-service" class="required span4" multiple="">
        <optgroup label="Capelli">
              <option selected="false" value="14">Colore capelli</option
        </optgroup>
        <optgroup label="Nessuna categoria">
              <option selected="false" value="13">Taglio capelli</option>
              <option selected="false" value="15">Mesh</option>
        </optgroup>                           
</select>
```

Now my goal is remove all option in select, so I've made this code:

```
$('#select-service')
  .find('option')
  .remove()
  .end();
```

but the problem's that this code remove only the `option` not the `optgroup`, how I can remove in one step `option` and `optgroup`?

Comment: Jss, your question title is a little misleading. One would guess that you want to remove a specific type of `option` rather than the parent of `option`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply pass two, comma-separated, selectors to the `find()` method:

```
$('#select-service').find('optgroup, option').remove();
```

You could also just remove all children elements for the same result:

```
$('#select-service').children().remove();
// or:
$('#select-service > *').remove();
```

The most concise approach would be to just remove the element using the [`.empty()` method](https://api.jquery.com/empty/):

```
$('#select-service').empty();
```

Comment: I did not know that .find accepts more of one parameter. Thanks

Comment: @Jss Please accept the answer if you find this answer helpful.

Comment: @Jss Yep, the `.find()` method accepts all valid CSS selectors. A more concise approach would be to just remove the elements using the `.empty()` method.

Comment: I accepts even the answer, but you have to wait the time of stackoverflow that allow me to accept the answer. Thanks again, have nice day :)

Comment: @Jss Not only `find()` accepts comma separated selectors, but pretty much any jQuery method. Remember that jQuery objects are **sets** of 0 or more elements.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way

```
$('#select-service optgroup').remove()
```

Since `optgroup` is the parent of `option` it will remove it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
$('#select-service')
.find('optgroup')
.remove();
```

This will not only remove your optgroup, but all contents within it, meaning your option will also be removed.